# AnyLogic certain number of agents passing block at same time

Tags: simulation, anylogic

My problem can be thought of as a floodgate:
I want a predefined number of agents (e.g. 50) to run through this delay block at the same time. Since this is not possible in AnyLogic, I have divided the delay time by the number of desired agents.
[General Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvFRk.png).

The startHold should be open until the 50 agents have passed. The holdEnd should be blocked. When the queue contains the 50 agents, holdEnd should be opened, so that all agents can get out at once. Meanwhile startHold is still blocked, because otherwise more agents will come in. When there are no more agents in the queue, holdEnd is blocked again and startHold is opened.

My approach is the following:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUHpa.png)

Let a counting variable, which was initialized in the class, count up when the queue is entered. Unfortunately the variable counts over the runtime and the code doesn't quite work as expected.
Does anyone have a better approach? I would appreciate any idea or help.

Comment: What do you mean by *this is not possible in AnyLogic*? You can set the capacity of the queue in block...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a wait block only and nothing else

and on the wait block on enter you do this:

```
if(self.size()==50){
self.freeAll();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Felipe, didn't know this block until now. But whats up with an else condition in your suggested answer? In my simulation I have different types of resources. At the start of my simulation I define several parameters to the different resources (machines). So this looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/rOl0FOZ
So if the condition isn't true for e.g. machine 1, the program jumps to the default case. Is there some code for an possible else-Block, something like "self.stayInWaitBlockUntilIfConditionIsTrue"? Didn't find on AnyLogic help page.

Comment: you should create a new question for this since it's a completely different question... for now if you ask something incomplete, you need to accept to get an incomplete answer